# Convert phones to calculation

Tags: code-golf, string, math

## Introduction

[OnePlus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OnePlus) is a Chinese smartphone manufacturer founded in December 2013. Their latest phone, OnePlus 5, was unveiled on June 20, 2017.

I am sure you have seen that the name of the phone can easily be translated to a sum.

`OnePlus` can be written like `1+` thus `OnePlus 2 = (1+ 2) = 3`

## Input

The name of one OnePlus phone. The above list in the only possible input

```
OnePlus 1
OnePlus 2
OnePlus X
OnePlus 3
OnePlus 3T
OnePlus 5
```

## Output

The sum of the name (a number **not a string**)

```
OnePlus 1 => 2
OnePlus 2 => 3
OnePlus X => an integer
OnePlus 3 => 4
OnePlus 3T => 27 (T = Today = 23 thus 1+3+23=27)
OnePlus 5 => 6
```

## Rules

The input can be written in different versions. This applies to every names. For example

```
OnePlus 1
OnePlus1
One+ 1
One+1
1+ 1
1+1
```

- The output for `OnePlus X` is an integer that should be different from the other phones names. Whatever you want except `2,3,4,27,6`
- The `T` in `OnePlus 3T` will always be `23` which is the day I am posting this.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution (in bytes) wins.

Comment: Is `One` case-sensitive? What about inputs like `One                    +   1`(arbitrary number of spaces between the tokens)?

Comment: Do we have to support all different versions?

Comment: @officialaimm `One` and `Plus` are case-sensitive. You only have to rely to the provided format

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer All the versions provided in the rules sections. Not less, Not more

Comment: @Downvoter Can I have an explanation ?

Comment: Can the being considered advertisement? Or Spam?

Comment: @sergiol If this is the case, I will remove my post. I was just trying to find a good challenge. In anyway, I am linked to the OnePlus company

Comment: Didn't understand. You are linked or not linked? => @Weedoze

Comment: @sergiol I am **not** linked. Sorry for the bad English hehe

Comment: How are there answers to this? Am I missing something or just stupid?

Comment: "*The input can be written in different versions*" has two issues. Firstly it's not clear whether this is a restriction (your code must handle all of them) or a concession (you choose which one to handle). Secondly, specification by example is not specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 10 bytes

```
0Uθ.VT26:>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f/fIPTQusMr9MJCjMys7P7/989LDcgpLVYwDgEA)

`θ` has been replaced by `®è` on TIO since it hasn't been pulled there yet. Alternatively, `¤` would work too.

Explanation:

```
0Uθ.VT26:> "Accepts a single line from STDIN"\
0          "Push 0"\
 U         "Assign to X"\
  θ        "(implicit input)"\ "Take the last element"\
   .V      "Eval as 05AB1E code"\
     T     "Push 10"\
      26   "Push 26"\
        :  "Infinitely replace"\
         > "Increment"\
```

Comment: Though the question is not so clear, in your solution, `OnePlus 4T` is outputting same as `OnePlus 3T`

Comment: @officialaimm I don't think we'll ever get such input.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>26</s> 16 bytes

*-10 bytes thanks to @MartinEnder*

```
O
1
T
995
.
$*
1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w35/LkCuEy9LSlEuPS0WLy/D/f/@81ICc0mIFQy4YywjOioCzjBGsEDjTFAA)

Comment: The best way to write a test suite is to put `%(G\`` in the header, which simply applies the program to each line individually. You can shorten `\D\n\n\d` to `.` and the final stage to a simple `1`: https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/K@q4Z7w35/LkCuEy9LSlEuPS0WLy/D/f/@81ICc0mIFQy4YywjOioCzjBGsEDjTFAA

Comment: @MartinEnder thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 21 bytes

20 bytes of code + `-p` flag.

```perl
$_=/\d$/?$&+1:27*/T/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9r6xYAKQVdAv@q8Tb6sekqOjbq6hpG1oZmWvph@j/t1ZQiVfQs1VQislTslZQVnBMScnMS1dIVMhLLc/JzEtVKMlXyE3MBtIZqQr5pSUFpSUKyTmpiUWpRf/981IDckqLFQy5YCwjOCsCzjJGsELgTFMA)

If the input ends with an integer (`/\d$/`), then we add one to it (`$&+1`) and outputs it. Otherwise, we output `27*/T/` which is `27` if the inputs contains a `T`, and `0` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), 138 bytes

```cs
using System.Linq;s=>s.Replace("One","1").Replace("Plus","+").Replace("T","+23").Replace("X","9").Split('+').Select(e=>int.Parse(e)).Sum()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nZDBisIwEIbvfYrQiwnVgisepLaXBU@KZRXWa4ijBNLEzaSCLD57d1pkFW/tHEL4ki/zZxROlPPQ1Kjtme1uGKBK19r@ZFHEqJSRiKz07uxl1ZHfbm0LgwxasavTR7aR2nLxf/S81Nbj2VVt1RKDp05jbUPBTnnUYF5g@gUXIxXweGshHsfTWDxRaWoklryyfQs@Zq/oQGhBYHcxOvBRMqItGFCBQ15Qt7SUHoGDIF5XXDSPD75l/HQWnYH02@sANAfgpy5Vm4JRLpH1tQZJ7DDImg2z9oO0eV8r6T/ApJ8xfW9x73b35g8)

Comment: It's a lot shorter to just check the last character of the input. Is it a digit: output that digit + 1; is it `T`: output 27; else / is it `X`: output an unique digit like 0 or 9.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, <s>79</s> 61 bytes

```java
s->{int x=s.charAt(s.length()-1);return x<58?x-47:x<85?27:9;}
```

**Explanation:**

[Try it here with all possible test cases.](https://tio.run/##pZJfS8MwFMXf9ykue2oJDWRaNtfN4QdwCvNBEB9iFrfMLi1NOiqjn71mf3zVA4X2oenh5p7fOTt5kElRartbf3Uql87RozT2OCAy1uvqUypNy9Pn@YBUtPKVsRtycRYO2/CGx3npjaIlWZpT55L740nbzB1XW1k9@MjxXNuN30ZxIuKs0r6uLDWzdLJoktvxtJlN0sVoPL3L2i67jCzrjzyMvE4@FGZN@7DY9fq3d5LxZavVt/N6z4va8zL88rmNLFfR8Mnq57x2JIbxedX/lSNY@Qorb3DlCyxN/1JiM2AqMBSYCYwEJ9ITCMNKwrCGMKweDOsGA4vB@raCYQwwBBgBDADov499gTRAIPkLJH2BZC@g5EW/3AVDfCO2EdeIacjzr@V20HY/)

```java
s->{                             // Method with String parameter and integer return-type
  int x=s.charAt(s.length()-1);  //  Get the last characters of the input
  return x<58?                   //  If it's a digit:
          x-47                   //   Return that digit + 1
         :x<85?                  //  Else if it's a 'T':
          27                     //   Return 27
         :                       //  Else (it's a 'X')
          9;                     //   Return 9 (unique digit other than 2,3,4,6,27)
}                                // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), <s>65</s> <s>63</s> 48 bytes

```c
f(char*s){s+=strlen(s)-1;s=*s?*s^84?*s-47:27:9;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S9ZNT07@/z9NIzkjsUirWLO6WNu2uKQoJzVPo1hT19C62Far2F6rOM7CBEjqmphbGZlbWVrX/ufKTczM09DkquZSAIKCosy8kjQNJdWUmDwlHSDDPy81IKe0WMFQSVPTGr8SI8JKIggrMSZCSQhhNaZ4lWhD/VPL9f9rXr5ucmJyRioA)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, <s>87</s> 51 bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` and outputs OnePlus math to the VBE immediate window

```vba
i=Asc(Right([A1],1)):?IIf(i<58,i-47,IIf(i<85,27,9))
```

### Old Version

Anonymous VBE immediate window function that takes input from cell `[A1]` that and outputs OnePlus math to the VBE immediate window

```vba
?Application.Evaluate("="&Replace(Replace(Replace([A1],"One",1),"Plus","+"),"T","+23"))
```

#### Input/Output

As a result of the `Application.Evaluate` call this solution is afforded access to all of the Excel WorkSheet Functions

```vba
[A1]="OnePlus 3T"
?Application.Evaluate("="&Replace(Replace(Replace([A1],"One",1),"Plus","+"),"T","+23"))
 23

[A1]="OnePlusPi()"
?Application.Evaluate("="&Replace(Replace(Replace([A1],"One",1),"Plus","+"),"T","+23"))
 4.14159265358979

[A1]="One+Day(Now())"
?Application.Evaluate("="&Replace(Replace(Replace([A1],"One",1),"Plus","+"),"T","+23"))
 26
```